# C function to convert from decimal to octal using "mask and shift" technique

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm doing a C program for a class where I have to write a function in which I convert decimal to octal but the tricky part is I have to use the "mask and shift" technique.

This is what I have so far but am not very confident it is the best route to go about this considering my calculations have been very far off:

```
int y = 8;
int decimal = 230;
char base4Answer[32];
int firstDigit;
int secondDigit;

if(y==8){

    const int mask1 = (7 << 3);
    const int mask2 = (7 << 0);
    firstDigit = (decimal & mask1);
    secondDigit = (decimal & mask2);
    printf("Octal Representation of Binary Number: %i%i\n", ascii[firstDigit], ascii[secondDigit]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for being straightforward that this is class work.

Comment: Do you know how to convert using the pen-and-paper technique?

Comment: I know how to convert through division but that is all.

Comment: Division by `8`, right? How can you divide by `8` using shifting? The next question would be how can you take a remainder of such a division using masking. If you answer these - you are good.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but would it require a right shift of 8 bits?

Comment: Okay ill look into that thank you

Comment: 8 bits is 2^8. 2 raised to the what power is 8?

Comment: 3 ofcourse, so should I be shifting 3 bits!?

Comment: @Daniel Grab a calculator and do some experiments. But I would suggest you to learn a bit about numeral representations and related math.

Comment: The thing I do not understand is how these binary terms will be useful if I will be going all the way up to the number 7 for octal?

Comment: yes.  shift 3 bits.  you can check your answer using the %o specifier... e.g. `printf("the answer should be %o\n", decimal);`